# Mysql timestamp query insert

Tags: mysql

What is the problem with this query?

```
INSERT INTO acfrac (username,id,count,time) VALUES ("John Smith", 10, 0,2006-06-07 09:44:33.0)
```

It gives me the following error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '09:44:33.0)' at line 1

Comment: In addition to quoting problems, `count` is reserved word. You almost certainly need to escape it. ie enclose it in back tics.

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote your time stamp. In mysql, if the field you're entering is not an integer, it must be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO acfrac (username,id,count,time) VALUES ("John Smith", 10, 0,'2006-06-07 09:44:33.0')
```

The date and datetime values need to be enclosed in single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I just encounter the same problem with you, I just saw the comment and add quotes with my time-stamp data type column and finally it going to work. It helps me a lot.